# How to trigger event based on invalid manual edit of text field in a jSpinner outside min/max range

Tags: java, swing, jspinner, jformattedtextfield

I have a java swing UI jSpinner component which accepts double values and has a minimum and maximum allowable ranges set.  The issue is that when the user manually enters a value in the jFormattedTextField part of the component which is outside of the min / max range and the focus leaves the text field the value is immediately rejected and reverted the the last previous valid value, (which is the expected and correct behavior for the component).

The user has requested that the behavior be changed such that when an invalid value is entered and the focus leaves the text field instead of just reverting to the last valid value it should be reverting to the maximum or minimum valid value depending on if the user entered an invalid value which was either greater than the maximum allowable or less than the allowable minimum.

For example if the spinner's minimum / maximum ranges are set to (1,10) and the user manually enters a value of 20 then the text field should bet set to 10, not the last valid value which was present in the jSpinner's model.

I have tried quite a few different ways to resolve this issue including at attaching a KeyListener to the the underlying JFormattedTextField as well as a PropertyChangeListener to the Jspinner's Number/Default editor but it seems like the main issue is that I am unable to get the invalid value's actual value so that I can determine if it is outside the range either above the max or below the min.

Using a KeyListener (Which i realize is NOT the appropriate way to handle the input of a JFormattedTextField) I am able to at least catch the key strokes but with the following code the most I am able to do is catch an exception which lets me know that the input value is outside the min/max range and nothing more.

In the code example the value I am receiving is as the 'dirtyValue' is always the last valid value and never the actual invalid newly entered user input.
I am totally out of ideas.  Can anyone help provide some insight?

I have tried using a KeyListener, a propertyChangeListener and an DocumentListener.

```
private JFormattedTextField tf = ((JSpinner.NumberEditor)
jSpinnerTiming.getEditor()).getTextField();

((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)jSpinnerTiming.getEditor()).getTextField().
              addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

              @Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { 

              }

              @Override public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { 

              }

              @Override public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { 
    try {        tf.commitEdit(); } catch
              (ParseException e1) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e1.printStackTrace(); } 
    double dirtyValue = (double)tf.getValue(); 
    double max = ALLOWABLE_MAX;
    double min = ALLOWABLE_MIN;
              if (dirtyValue > max) { 
    jSpinnerTiming.setValue(max);
              ; } else if(dirtyValue < min){
              jSpinnerTiming.setValue(min); 
              } }

              });
```

Comment: This is a shared legacy component and there is much logic based off the current implementation's min/max making a refactor to remove the min/max very complicated if not impossible.

Comment: I was able to get a solution working using a FocusListener, check solution posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I was able to get working using a FocusListener, although I am not sure how correct it is.

```
private JFormattedTextField tf = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) jSpinnerTiming.getEditor()).getTextField();
((JSpinner.DefaultEditor)jSpinnerTiming.getEditor()).getTextField().addFocusListener(new  FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                // The unchecked user input value 
                double dirtyValue = Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());

                // Get Minimum and Maximum values from jSpinner's Model 
                double max = (Double) ((SpinnerNumberModel) jSpinnerTiming.getModel()).getMaximum();//MAX_ALLOWED_RATE
                double min = (Double) ((SpinnerNumberModel) jSpinnerTiming.getModel()).getMinimum();//LOWEST_ALLOWABLE_RATE;

                if (dirtyValue > max) { 
                    jSpinnerTiming.setValue(max);
                } else if(dirtyValue < min){
                    jSpinnerTiming.setValue(min);
                } 
            }
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that JSpinner keeps everything internal.  The editor installs an [AbstractFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter.html) which never allows below the minimum or above the maximum, so you never get a chance to react to those conditions.

Since it’s nearly impossible to intercept an existing AbstractFormatter’s behavior, I would just create the JSpinner with no minimum or maximum, and enforce those bounds manually in a ChangeListener:

```
private static JSpinner createSpinner() {

    double initialValue = 20;

    SpinnerModel model =
        new SpinnerNumberModel(initialValue, null, null, 1d);

    model.addChangeListener(e -> {
        double value = ((Number) model.getValue()).doubleValue();
        if (value < ALLOWABLE_MIN) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> model.setValue(ALLOWABLE_MIN));
        } else if (value > ALLOWABLE_MAX) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> model.setValue(ALLOWABLE_MAX));
        }
    });

    return new JSpinner(model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the `AbstractFormatter` of the `JFormattedTextField` of the `DefaultEditor` of the `JSpinner` (via a custom `AbstractFormatterFactory`), like the following code:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatter;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.AbstractFormatterFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JSpinner.DefaultEditor;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;

public class Main {

    public static class IntegerFormatter extends AbstractFormatter {
        private final int min, max;

        public IntegerFormatter(final int min, final int max) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        @Override
        public Object stringToValue(final String text) throws ParseException {
            try {
                //This is where we compare for out of bounds values:
                final int val = Integer.parseInt(text);
                if (val < min)
                    return min;
                if (val > max)
                    return max;
                return val;
            }
            catch (final NumberFormatException nfx) {
                //Find where in the string is the parsing error (so as to return ParseException accordingly).
                int i = 0;
                for (final int cp: text.codePoints().toArray()) {
                    if (!Character.isDigit(cp))
                        throw new ParseException("Not a digit.", i);
                    ++i;
                }
                //Should not happen:
                throw new ParseException("Failed to parse input \"" + text + "\".", 0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String valueToString(final Object value) throws ParseException {
            return Objects.toString(value);
        }
    }

    public static class IntegerFormatterFactory extends AbstractFormatterFactory {
        private final int min, max;

        public IntegerFormatterFactory(final int min, final int max) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        @Override
        public AbstractFormatter getFormatter(final JFormattedTextField tf) {
            if (!(tf.getFormatter() instanceof IntegerFormatter))
                return new IntegerFormatter(min, max);
            return tf.getFormatter();
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final SpinnerNumberModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, -10, 10, 1);
        final JSpinner spin = new JSpinner(model);
        spin.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));

        ((DefaultEditor) spin.getEditor()).getTextField().setFormatterFactory(
                new IntegerFormatterFactory((Integer) model.getMinimum(), (Integer) model.getMaximum())
        );

        final JPanel contents = new JPanel(); //FlowLayout.
        contents.add(spin);
        contents.add(new JButton("Click me to change focus!"));

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Spinner out of bounds");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(contents);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't [InputVerifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) be appropriate here?

Comment: @Abra I have never used InputVerifier before. But as I see from the documentation, it would not allow the user to transfer focus for invalid input. Is that correct? If so, then I should note that we want the user to be able to transfer focus and at the same time control in a way the value set by the text field to the model. That's why I chose to make the input verifying inside the formatter. I will try InputVerifier now and notify you in a moment.

Comment: @Abra as I've seen, InputVerifier can be used in conjunction with the custom formatter. It just does not allow to transfer focus if the input is invalid. We however want to first change the value given (if it is outside range) and then transfer focus. So the InputVerifier won't let the user transfer focus. So I don't think that it has to do with the question. It may be better practice though.

Comment: @Abra I think one could possibly change the input text (via *setText*) inside the InputVerifier's *verify* method. For example while we are checking if the value is invalid inside the input verifier, we could also change the value via setValue/setText. But I don't think InputVerifier is intended for such usage.